# How can I embed a CR+LF in a command issued at the Windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line, newline, windows-shell

How can I embed a CR + LF in a command I'm using at the Windows command prompt without actually issuing the command?

Example:

`C:\Windows\system32>myprog -u user -p pass -text "Sincerely,\nRob"`

Is it up to myprog to do handle the line break?  I figured there must be some way to represent a line break that the Windows command line would recognize.

Comment: Could you do something like, C:\Windows\system32>myprog -u user -p pass -text < RobSig.txt? Or would that not work with what you're doing?

Comment: That won't work because the -text parameter is expecting a quoted string to follow.

Comment: I tried adding the -text command to RobSig.txt and piped that in, which worked, but each new line in the file is treated as a separate command. So, it thinks Rob is a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can understand, it is upon your program to decipher the input that it receives (i.e., how to treat the data from the stream). Usually a carriage return/line feed is taken as separators.

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to pass the ascii numbers 13 and 10.
in the windows world a 'new line' is actually \r\n (carriage return and newline) so you'll need them both passed.